# Not able to create pod in openshift (The runAsGroup does not match the field value from the annotation in the namespace)

Tags: deployment, yaml, openshift

I am trying to deploy some applications using deploymentConfig. Below is the simplified version of yaml file for postgres.

```
apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
labels:
  template: postgres
message: |-
  To test deployment for postgres.
metadata:
  annotations:
    description: Deploys postgress on Openshift.
    openshift.io/display-name: postgress
    openshift.io/long-description: postgres
    openshift.io/provider-display-name: xxxx
    tags: database
    template.openshift.io/bindable: "false"
  name: postgres    
objects:

- apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      template.alpha.openshift.io/wait-for-ready: 'true'
    labels:
      app: ${APPLICATION_NAME}
      template: postgresql-ephemeral-template
    name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: POSTGRESQL_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-user
                name: postgresql
          - name: POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-password
                name: postgresql
          - name: POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-name
                name: postgresql
          image: rhel8/postgresql-12
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - "/usr/libexec/check-container"
              - "--live"
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
            protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - "/usr/libexec/check-container"
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
          securityContext: 
            capabilities: {}
            privileged: false
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/pgsql/data
            name: postgresql-data
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: 
          runAsUser: 2222
          runAsGroup: 1111
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        volumes:
        - name: postgresql-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ${PERSISTENT_VOLUME_CLAIM_DB}

    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: postgresql:12
          namespace: airflow-data-factory
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange

- apiVersion: v1
  stringData:
    database-name: ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
    database-password: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
    database-user: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
    connection-string: postgresql+psycopg2://${POSTGRESQL_USER}:${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRESQL_HOST}:5432/${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
    result-backend: db+postgresql://${POSTGRESQL_USER}:${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRESQL_HOST}:5432/${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: ${APPLICATION_NAME}
      template: postgresql-ephemeral-template
    name: postgresql
  type: Opaque

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: ${APPLICATION_NAME}
      template: postgresql-ephemeral-template
    name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
      port: 5432
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5432
    selector:
      name: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: ${PERSISTENT_VOLUME_CLAIM_DB}
    namespace: airflow-data-factory
  spec:
    storageClassName: openshift-trident-ext4
    accessModes:
      - "ReadWriteOnce"
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: ${PERSISTENT_VOLUME_CLAIM_DB_SIZE}

parameters:
- description: Name of the application
  displayName: Application name
  name: APPLICATION_NAME
  value: postgres
- description: PostgreSQL host
  displayName: PostgreSQL hostname
  name: POSTGRESQL_HOST
  value: postgresql
  required: true
- description: Username for PostgreSQL user that will be used for accessing the database
  displayName: PostgreSQL connection username
  from: 'user[a-z0-9]{5}'
  generate: expression
  name: POSTGRESQL_USER
  required: true
- description: Password for the PostgreSQL connection user
  displayName: PostgreSQL connection password
  from: '[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}'
  generate: expression
  name: POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
  required: true
- description: Database name for PostgreSQL database
  displayName: PostgreSQL connection database
  from: 'airflow[a-z0-9]{5}'
  generate: expression
  name: POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
  required: true
- description: Attached PERSISTENT volume claim name for storing metadata in PostgreSQL database
  displayName: PERSISTENT volume claim name (database)
  name: PERSISTENT_VOLUME_CLAIM_DB
  value: storage-db-pvc
- description: Size of the metadata volume storage
  displayName: Metadata volume storage size
  name: PERSISTENT_VOLUME_CLAIM_DB_SIZE
  value: "1Gi"
```

When I execute this template, I am getting following error:

```
Stop retrying: couldn't create deployer pod for "zzzzzzzzzz/postgresql-7": admission webhook "validate.kyverno.something-ignore" denied the request: policy Pod/namespace_name/postgresql-7-deploy for resource violations: add-securitycontext: update-runasgroup: The runAsGroup does not match the field value from the annotation in the namespace. ensure-readonly-lustre: ensure-readonly-lustre: preconditions not met
```

I have rechecked runAsUser and runAsGroup. And it is defined correctly according to scc.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

it failed with error to update runAsGroup but i am sure that it is correct. Is there amy problem with my template yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, runAsUser and runAsGroup violate OpenShift policies. In other words, you can't use them with OpenShift.

What is happening in OpenShift, it creates a random (big number, always >1000) user id which runs your pod and assigns it to the root group (id 0).

So you need to adjust your images so that permissions allow to run it by someone belonging to the root group.

Now, for your particular case, start with removing securityContext completely and see what happens - it may just work as is. If not, look at what resources need access by the user running the container and make sure they are accessible by a user with groupid 0.

Comment: Even after I remove it, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: So I added the uid and gid to the image as suggested by you but still i am getting the same error. Please find my dockerFile for the same: 
    From centos/postgresql-12-centos7:1

ARG USERNAME=postgres
ARG USER_UID=4444
ARG USER_GID=2222

USER root

RUN groupmod --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && usermod --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && chown -R $USER_UID:$USER_GID /var/lib/pgsql \
    && chown -R $USER_UID:$USER_GID  /var/run/postgresql

CMD ["postgres"]

Comment: Wait, after the first step is the error really the same? Should be a different error, or you may have security context set elsewhere.

Comment: but when i do Deployment instead of DeploymentConfig, it worked.